# What does the "Apollo file type information" extra field in GZIP do?

Tags: gzip

In GZIP there is an optional extra field. The only defined type in [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952) is "Apollo file type information". The RFC tells us it's SI1 and SI2 bytes ('A', 'P'), but it says nothing about it's content. I couldn't find any information on Google either.

What is it's content? Can you explain me it's format?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://jim.rees.org/apollo-archive/ . In there you can find https://jim.rees.org/apollo-archive/gzip-1.2.4-patch.tar.Z , which patches gzip to process the Apollo extra field in order to save and restore Apollo-unique file attributes.

By the way, there is an typo in RFC 1951 for that ID. It says:

```
0x41 ('A')  0x70 ('P')
```

The hex values are correct, but the second letter is not. It should read:

```
0x41 ('A')  0x70 ('p')
```

This is all for [an ancient workstation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Computer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know it's a dumb question, but are there any example gzip files with Apollo extension?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.